# Display string of text in textbox based on the multiple checkbox in userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I created a simple userform with 4 checkboxes and 1 textbox.

[image]

I want to be able to display sentences based on the checkbox that is clicked.
if checkboxSwimming pool is check, i want to display this string:
The caller mentioned about Swimming Pool.

if checkbox swimmingpool and checkbox balcony is check, i want to display this string.

The caller mentioned about Swimming Pool.
The caller mentioned about Balcony.

and son on.

here's my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'If chkPool.Value = True Then
'txtComment.Text = "The caller asked about Swimming Pool."

'ElseIf chkBalcony.Value = True Then
'txtComment.Text = "The caller asked about Balcony and Patio."

'End If

Select Case test_test

Case chkPool.Value = True
txtComment.Text = "The caller asked about Swimming Pool."


Case chkPool.Value = True & chkBalcony.Value = True
txtComment.Text = "The caller asked about Swimming Pool."
txtComment.Text = "The caller asked about balcony."


End Select




End Sub
```

Comment: Here's the string of text that I wanted to display based on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

txtComment.Text = ""

If chkPool.Value = True Then
    txtComment.Text = txtComment.Text & "The caller asked about Swimming Pool." & Chr(10)
End If

If chkBalcony.Value = True Then
    txtComment.Text = txtComment.Text & "The caller asked about Balcony and Patio." & Chr(10)
End If

'... add more IF clauses for the other check boxes here...


End Sub
```

Just make sure that the text box is `MultiLine = True`.

Comment: Hello Ralph, it's working then, this is the text that display.